# three.js - Objects farther away from camera gets jagged textures

Tags: three.js, textures

I'm struggeling with textures on objects that are a bit farther back in the scene. The textures become very jagged, and creates a disturbing effect as the camera moves. I've tried changing the anisotropy, and I've tried changing the min and mag filters, but nothing seems to help at all.

Code I'm using to load textures (all textures are 1024px by 1024px):

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
var texloader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
texloader.load('static/3d/' + name + '.jpg', function (image) {
    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    texture.anisotropy = 1;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearMipmapLinearFilter;
});
```

You can see it in action here: http://www.90595.websys.sysedata.no/

Answer (score 2):

gaitat is wrong, you do want the mipmaps.
The problem with your code is that they are not generated.
Using the console, I found that while "generateMipmaps" in your textures is set to "true", mipmaps are not generated, as seen in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCWyO.jpg.

I looked at your textures, and I believe the mipmaps weren't generated due to your textures not being a power of 2 (e.g. 128x128, 256x256, 512x512). Try making your textures of width and height that are powers of 2 and I think the mipmaps will be generated and they won't look jagged anymore.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for really looking into it. Most of my textures are in the power of two, though: http://www.90595.websys.sysedata.no/static/3d/gibson.jpg as you can see there. Anything else I can try to force mipmaps?

Comment: Also seems like the mipmaps array is supposed to be empty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158014/an-error-when-try-to-use-mipmaping-in-three-js

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, Lucas, but in the end it was just setting the right mipmap filter...

Answer (score 0):

As objects move further away from the camera webgl uses textures automatically generated called mipmaps. These are of lower resolution. If you don't like them disable them by:

```
texture.generateMipmaps = false;
```

Comment: Hm... When I do that, the textures don't load at all. So all my objects are just black.

Comment: By default either .magFilter, .minFilter or both are set to use mipmaps. When you disable mipmaps you also have to change .magFilter and .minFilter

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I thought I'd tried all the different mipmap filters, but apparently no. So this is what ended up doing the trick:

```
texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapNearestFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
```

Didn't need the `anisotropy` at all.

Comment: In fact,for the mipmaps to work you need only the minFilter to be NearestMipMapNearestFilter or LinearMipMapLinearFilter ,magFilter can be just linear.